# Producing 3d model using input data from android studio app

Tags: java, android, 3d

Sorry, have looked everywhere but with no joy.  I want to produce an engineering phone app that will allow users to fill in a table of dimensions that can then produce a 3d model that can be emailed to their pc and then opened with some 3d software (e.g. 3d builder, sketchup, autocrat, or similar). Essentially I am trying to find out if models can be produced for a 3d package using code on my app rather than doing the drawing from scratch in the software.  Can this be done in android studio?

Comment: I don't think so if you'll find any luck doing it in android studio check out the unity forums you're going to have a lot more luck.(Unity works with C#)But it's so much simpler.You can learn it in a few days for what you want to do.Not for making great games for sure that takes years ;)

Comment: Thanks steve moretz

Comment: Hope this helped I'll post the comment as an answer if it helped you,you can accept and upvote it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think so if you'll find any luck doing it in android studio check out the unity forums you're going to have a lot more luck.(Unity works with C#)But it's so much simpler.You can learn it in a few days for what you want to do.Not for making great games for sure that takes years ;)